# NameError: uninitialized constant Minitest::VERSION

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I'm using Rails 4.1 and Ruby 2.0.0. I'm trying to set up testing with `minitest-rails` and I'm running into this strange error. When I include:

```
require 'minitest/spec'
```

In my 'spec_helper' file it give me a NameError: uninitialized constant Minitest::VERSION error. When I comment out this line, everything seems to work fine. The odd thing is that 'minitest/autorun' is also in there and not causing any problems. Maybe you guys can shed some light on what's going on here.

`spec_helper.rb`:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "test"
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

require 'minitest/spec'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'minitest-rails'
require 'minitest-rails-capybara'
```

`Rakefile`:

```
    require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

    Pinteresting::Application.load_tasks

    namespace :test do
      task :run do
        ENV["RACK_ENV"] = "test"
        $LOAD_PATH.unshift("lib", "spec")
        if ARGV[1]
          require_relative ARGV[1]
        else
          Dir.glob("./spec/**/*_spec.rb").each { |file| require file }
        end
      end
    end
```

`.spec`:

```
    require "spec_helper"

    describe "Test" do
      describe "When two is equal to two" do 
        it "asserts true" do
          assert_equal(2, 2)
        end
      end
    end
```

Stack trace:

```
    nbp-93-202:pinteresting Frank$ rake test:run
    rake aborted!
    NameError: uninitialized constant Minitest::VERSION
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/minitest-5.3.4/lib/minitest/unit.rb:22:in `<class:Unit>'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/minitest-5.3.4/lib/minitest/unit.rb:21:in `<module:Minitest>'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/minitest-5.3.4/lib/minitest/unit.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/minitest-5.3.4/lib/minitest/spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/Frank/Desktop/pinteresting/spec/spec_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/Frank/Desktop/pinteresting/spec/diagnostic_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/Frank/Desktop/pinteresting/Rakefile:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
    /Users/Frank/Desktop/pinteresting/Rakefile:12:in `each'
    /Users/Frank/Desktop/pinteresting/Rakefile:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    Tasks: TOP => test:run
```

Comment: Do you see this error when running `bundle install`? Including the stack trace would help

Comment: I added the stack trace

Comment: Does the error still arises if you change the order in the requires, that is, first require 'minitest/autorun' and then 'minitest/spec'?

Comment: I switched them around and that did the trick, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interestingly, if try to run or require a file with just the two requires `minitest/spec` and `minitest/autorun` the interpreter raises a warning saying that `you should require 'minitest/autorun' instead or add "gem 'minitest'" before require 'minitest/autorun'`, although it doesn't rise the `NameError`to me.

So switching the require statements around (in order to first require `minitest/autorun`) seems to do the trick. Requiring `minitest`in the first place seems to do the trick also.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can resolve this warning by making your implementation simpler. In `spec/spec_helper.rb`:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require "minitest/rails"
require "minitest/rails/capybara"
```

You are missing the require for `rails/test_help`. Did you remove that for a specific reason?

In `Rakefile`:

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

Rails.application.load_tasks

Rails::TestTask.new("test:spec" => "test:prepare") do |t|
  t.pattern = "spec/**/*_spec.rb"
end

Rake::Task["test:run"].enhance ["test:spec"]
```

And now run either `$ rake test:spec` to run all your specs, or `$ rake test` to run all your tests. The reason behind keeping the rake tasks under the `test` namespace is because this is what Spring keys on to use the running test environment. Spring uses the task namespace, not the directory name.